# Let T be a tree on n vertices and let $n_r$ be the number of vertices of degree r. Show that $n_1$=2+$\sum (r-2)$ $n_r$

Tags: graph-theory

> Show that $n_1$=2+$\sum (r-2)$ $n_r$, sum is from $r \ge 2$. I have no idea to solve this. What i know just (maxdegree of T)$\ge n_1$

Answer (score 1):

There are two facts you need to prove this:

1. A tree of order $n$ has $n-1$ edges.
2. In any graph, the sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges, so $2|E| = \sum deg(v)$.

So try express express the sum of the degrees in terms of the $n_r$. How to do so is given in the spoiler below:

> Since there are $n_r$ vertices of degree $r$, $\sum deg(v) = \sum r\cdot n_r$.

And then you can rewrite $n$ in terms of the $n_r$:

> $n = n_1 + n_2 + \dots + n_k$, where $k$ is the maximum degree of $T$.

Finally, you can put this all together (try do so without looking here):

> $2|E| = 2(n-1) = 2n-2 = \sum r\cdot n_r$, so, taking all sums from $r=2$, we get: $$2n_1 + \sum 2\cdot n_r - 2 = n_1 + \sum r\cdot n_r$$ and so $$n_1 = 2 + \sum (r-2)\cdot n_r$$